# SELECT * FROM MSISCSIInitiator_TargetClass giving Generic failure error

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012, wmi

I'm trying to find my machine is iscsi storage, but below function is giving Generic failure:

```
StackTrace = "   at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus 
errorCode)\r\n   at  system.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()\r\n  at     System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.get_Count()\r\n
```

My code:

```
    private string GetISCSInfo(string DeviceID)
    {
        string StorageType = "Local";
        try
        {
            var scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\ROOT\\WMI");
            **SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM MSISCSIInitiator_TargetClass");**

            ManagementObjectSearcher iscsiSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
            ManagementObjectCollection iscsiCollection;
            string iscsiDeviceID = null;

             ***//Get() is calling using validSearch function in this function error is throwing***
            if (validSearch(iscsiSearcher, out iscsiCollection))
            {

                foreach (ManagementObject item in iscsiCollection)
                {
                    if (validField(item, "InitiatorName"))
                    {
                        iscsiDeviceID = item["InitiatorName"].ToString();

                        if (string.Equals(iscsiDeviceID, DeviceID, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            StorageType = "iSCSI";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return StorageType;
    }

  //Error getting while count is checking
  public bool validSearch(ManagementObjectSearcher searcher,
                                        out ManagementObjectCollection collection)
    {
        collection = searcher.Get();
        bool result = false;
        try
        {
            if (collection.Count > 0)
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.TraceWarning("Exception caught while running query: " + e);

            //Invalid
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: change `foreach (ManagementObject item` to `foreach (var item` and try again

Comment: Thanks, @Bizhan but It's not going to "for" loop. Getting error from validSearch function called. while checking collection.count > 0  it will throw error

Comment: could it be an access violation? are you running it with elevated privilege?

Comment: @Bizhan I'm having few other wmi queries which are executing properly

Comment: I remember once I was trying to read HDD serial number and it required admin access. Just a guess

Answer (score 0):

I was connected to remote machine with cimv2 so query which required wmi connection I given command like below

```
var scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\ROOT\\WMI");
SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM MSISCSIInitiator_TargetClass");**

ManagementObjectSearcher iscsiSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
```

here again we need to call scope.connect()

Issue resolved.